# Back Button in JQueryMobile when a Form was Submitted

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a JQM page with a form. When a form is submitted, the result will be displayed in another JQM page with some links. Clicking the link will go to another JQM page with back button on it:

```
<a href="#" data-icon="back" data-rel="back" >Back</a>
```

The problem is that clicking the back button will go to the form instead of the second page (the result page). Any workaround on this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is. Remove data-rel="back" and add this code. If you third page has an id thirdPage use this event to get a id of a last page and add click event on back button so it can return you to your second page.

```
$('#thirdPage').live('pagebeforeshow', function (e, data) {
    //below is a beck button of page #thirdPage
    $('#thirdPage-backbtn').bind('click', function(e) {
        $.mobile.changePage( "#" + data.prevPage.attr('id') , {transition: "none"} );
    });
}
```

If you need more information look here: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0rc1/docs/api/events.html, look for the data.prevPage.

Or you can use this:

```
<a href="" data-role="button" data-icon="back" onclick="history.go(-1);">Back</a>
```

I prefer first option, it is longer but gives you much more control.